# Run 3 monitors on two different video cards?

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, amd-graphics-card

Can I run 3 monitors on two different video cards?

I have an ATI and Nvidia brand card.

The ATI has 2 HDMI connections. They both work. Both cards are also picked up in Windows, one being the ATI and the other one as the Nvidia, but it says VGA Controller, although the card only takes 2 DVi. So, one DVI cable goes into that Nvidia card. 3 Monitors, but only 2 the HDMI ones from the ATI pick up, not the third one which is connected to the Nvidia via DVI.

How can I run three monitors then? I suppose I can't install both drivers, so I'm unsure what to do. Is this possible? I just want the Nvidia card to power the third screen, no gaming on it, nothing. Also the ATI is picked up as primary card as well, so no hurdle there.

**EDIT: Hm, just installed the Nvidia drivers and it picked up the third screen no problem. Hope there aren't any major conflicts. Will post this as an answer as correct when I'm able. Can't as a new user.**

Answer (score 0):

Hm, just installed the Nvidia drivers and it picked up the third screen no problem. Hope there aren't any major conflicts. Will mark this answer

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS. If you use windows XP or windows 2000 then no. Those do not support two different graphics drivers. If you use windows 7 (or more modern), Linux, BSD etc then yes, you can use both cards at the same time. Each with its own driver.